# Update a column in one table with the [column name] as value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

The app I was asked to update is generating a report using a few tables.

Table1 keeps id's and references to columns in another table with configuration items.

Table2 is a configuration table and is used to keep references to reports with values in dynamically added columns like usercol1, usercol2...usercol55.

I can't figure how to update tempname with the [column name] as value. I wrote the DDL below but the UPDATE query does not work, because `a.colnum` is not recognized as a column.

The report I need to be like this:

```
1   bob
2   john
3   jack
4   ben
```

If I write UPDATE as a regular inline query with concatenating `a.usercol + cast(a.colnum as varchar(2))`, the result I am getting:

```
1   usercol32
2   usercol2
3   usercol7
4   usercol7
```

So, I think I need to write UPDATE query as dynamic sql as in DDL below. As expected it is generating error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
> The multi-part identifier "a.colnum" could not be bound.

I could write a loop with additional table, dumping contents of the [colnum] into variable and updating the column with that variable... Is there way to write this query without a loop.

Here is DDL:

```
create table #Table1 (id int, colnum int)
create table #Table2 (id int, usercol1 varchar(20), usercol2 varchar(20), usercol3 varchar(20), usercol7 varchar(20), usercol32 varchar(20))

insert into #Table1(id, colnum) values(1, 32);
insert into #Table1(id, colnum) values(2, 2);
insert into #Table1(id, colnum) values(3, 7);
insert into #Table1(id, colnum) values(4, 7);

insert into #Table2(id, usercol32) values(1, 'bob');
insert into #Table2(id, usercol2) values(2, 'john');
insert into #Table2(id, usercol7) values(3, 'jack');
insert into #Table2(id, usercol7) values(4, 'ben');

CREATE TABLE #Temp    
(    
 tempid int,
 tempname varchar(20) 
)

insert into #Temp (tempid)
select id from #Table1

declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'update #Temp'
            + ' set tempname = a.usercol' + cast(a.colnum as varchar(2))
            + ' from #table1 a'
            + ' join #table2 b on a.id = b.id'
            + ' where #Temp.tempid = a.id'

exec (@sql)
select * from #Temp

drop table #Temp
drop table #Table1
drop table #Table2
```

Comment: you can do a giant mega update #temp set tempname = CASE colnum when 1 then usercol1 when 2 then usercol2... end . This design is... original, i'll give you that

Comment: Instead of dealing with all this craziness of looping and repeating yourself you should instead normalize your table. You have violated 1NF with what is called repeating groups (i.e. usercol1, usercol2, usercol3, etc...).

Comment: Yes, design is absolute nuts. I did not design it and unfortunately, there is not much I can do about it. When I do db design, I keep at least 3NF. Giant CASE is not an option because we don't know column names. I checked the table and noticed usercol50 and I think its not the end. Apparently, each time some transaction type is created, new usercol[n] is generated...

Answer (score 3):

As @siggemannen said you can produce those results with a large case expression e.g.

```
select t1.id
  , case
  when t1.colnum = 32 then t2.usercol32
  when t1.colnum = 7 then t2.usercol7
  when t1.colnum = 3 then t2.usercol3
  when t1.colnum = 2 then t2.usercol2
  else t2.usercol1
  end
from #Table1 t1
join #Table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id;
```

If you prefer to do it dynamically you have to think carefully about what is dynamic and what isn't... and you end up with

```
declare @Sql nvarchar(max) = '';

select @Sql = string_agg(
  'select '
  + convert(varchar(38),t1.id)
  + ' id, t2.usercol'
  + convert(varchar(32),t1.colnum)
  + ' UserName from #Table2 t2 where t2.id = '
  + convert(varchar(38),t1.id)
  , ' union all ')
from #Table1 t1

-- print(@Sql); -- Debug
execute sp_executesql @Sql;
```

Use the debug print statement to assist understanding.

Comment: The second version works! Wow, now I have to figure what is going on in that statement. Very neat.
Giant CASE is not an option. Those usercol[n] are generated when new transaction type is created. Not that often though... it seems at the rate of few new columns every year. Its a bit of a nightmare.

Comment: @user1706426 use the `PRINT` statement - thats how you debug dynamic SQL - cos then its static.

Comment: Yea, I know PRINT or SELECT work. The problem might be if the number of records fetched when generating report may run in hundreds or even couple of thousands. So, for each ID or row there will be a separate SELECT with UNION ALL... My feeling is this can not be good

Comment: @user1706426 you are totally right... its completely crap :) but goes with the design unfortunately. You can't dynamically select a different column from a joined table aside from with a sub-query.